# How to add Custom module in beaver builder plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a custom module using beaver builder.I have placed it plugin directory.On local host with using beaver builder light version it is working fine and custom module is showing in Advance Module tab properly.

But when I add this custom module on live site where I have installed premium version of Beaver builder..Custom module is not showing in Advance Module of page builder

Please help me how to make working this.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have figured this one out already, but let's still provide an answer to this question.

When you go to your Wordpress dashboard, navigate to **Settings > Page Builder > Modules**
Once there you have to make sure that you enabled your plugin by checking the according checkbox of the module.